Microsoft.Visual Studio.Diagnostics.Assert.Version 14.0.0.0 be Installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first
Im installiing app, and this happen. Please help
How to resolve this issue?

Microsoft.Visual Studio.Diagnostics.Assert.Version 14.0.0.0 be
Installed in the Global Assembly Cache enter image description here(GAC) first.


Please note that the [tag:assembly] tag is for questions about assembly language, and is not applicable here.  In future, please check the description of each tag before adding it.

Are you referring to installing Visual Studio or an app created from Visual Studio?
